# Quantile regression and linear regression coefficient comparison

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, quantile-regression

I am trying to understand the concept of quantile regression by modelling the monthly expenditure on insurance on several variables. The `R` package `quantreg` provides a function `rq()`, which can estimate coefficients for different quantiles and plot them nicely. What I do not understand is the relationship of the `qr()` and `lm()` coefficients in the plot:

[image]

Where the red line are the coefficients from linear regression. I would assume, that the red line would cross the black one at around the median. Also, the `education_level` variable seems completely off, when all of the `qr()` coefficients are negative and `lm()` one is highly positive. What is the logical explanation for that?

Thanks!